# How to delete / prune all tree nodes where the nodes do not exist in a separate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON tree representation:

```
let tree = [
    {
        "label": "Org01",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "Dist01",
                "children": [
                  {
                      "label": "School1",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "label": "class1",
                          "children": []
                        },
                        {
                          "label": "class2",
                          "children": []
                        }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                        "label": "School1tst",
                        "children": []
                  }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Dist02",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "contoso01",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "Dist A",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "label": "School A",
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "label": "classA",
                            "children": []
                          }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "School B",
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "label": "classB",
                            "children": []
                          }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Dist B",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "label": "School1",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "label": "class1",
                        "children": []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    ];
```

I have a list of nodes in an array like here:

```
let whitelist = ['class1', 'School1', 'Dist01'];
```

How can I delete all the nodes from the tree which do not exist in the above array. However parent nodes need to be displayed on the tree if their children are in the whitelist.

Deleting a specific node from the tree is possible for me, but I could not figure out a way to delete all nodes from the tree except the few which are in the array.

Final output required:

```
output = [
    {
        "label": "razor01",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "Dist01",
                "children": [
                  {
                      "label": "School1",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "label": "class1",
                          "children": []
                        }
                      ]
                  }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "contoso01",
        "children": [            
            {
                "label": "Dist B",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "label": "School1",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "label": "class1",
                        "children": []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }];
```

Thanks and I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: Your outer object's labels are not in the whitelist. Do you want an empty list returned?

Comment: @Viney , I have posted my code below which I had tried. Can you please check my solution but it does not seem to be right.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I need parent nodes need to be displayed on the tree if their children's labels are in the whitelist.

Comment: So `"label": "Dist B"` is not in the whitelist, but it has a child with `"label": "School1"`. So you want `contoso01` And `Dist B` in the final output? It might be clearer if you edit the question to show your desired output.

Comment: Yes that is right, that is the required final output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
function deleteNodes(tree, list) {
    if (tree.length > 0) {
            tree.forEach((node, i) => {
                this.deleteNodes(node.subItems, list);
                if (node.subItems) {
                    if (node.subItems.length === 0 && !list.includes(node.text)) 
                    {
                        tree.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const prunedNode = node => {
  const pruned = whitelist.includes(node.label) ? node : null;

  if (pruned) {
    node.children = node.children.reduce((prunedChildren, child) => {
      const prunedChildNode = prunedNode(child);
      if (prunedChildNode) {
        prunedChildren.push(prunedChildNode);
      }
      return prunedChildren;
    }, []);
  }

  return pruned;
};

console.log(prunedNode(tree));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done:

```
function filter(tree, list){
    let output = [];
    for(i in tree){
        if(list.indexOf(tree[i].label) >= 0){
            tree[i].children = filter(tree[i].children, list);
            output.push(tree[i]);
        }else{
            output = output.concat(filter(tree[i].children, list));
        }
    }
   return output;
}
```